# List index our of range in for loop

Tags: python

I'm running into list index errors in a for loop. I have a list of tuples with BIO markers, and want to combine Bs and Is together. For every item in the list that starts with B, append that B and all sequential Is in separate list.

I'm currently using a for loop to literate over all of the items in an enumerated list, using the index to peek ahead 1-3 positions for I markers. This isn't ideal, but it's what I did.

```py
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    word = []
    second = index + 1
    third = index +2
    forth = index +3
    if item == 'B' and l[second] == 'I' and l[third] == 'I' and l[forth] == 'I':
        word.append((item, l[second], l[third], l[forth]))
        word = " ".join(word[0])
...
    elif item == 'B':
        word.append(item)
        entities.append(word[0])

    else:
        pass
```

This works reasonably well, until I get towards the end of the list. If a B occurs at the end, I gt an index error because there is no second, third, or forth.

What is a better method of itrating over the list? Using a while loop?

Comment: The problem here isn't the iteration; it's that you're trying to _look ahead_ of the iteration.  As you found, that causes an error when you're near the end of the list.

Comment: And to add on to what @JohnGordon said, the answer to your question is to catch the end of a list and do something differently if at the end.

Comment: @Alex, from the Programing perspective, you can use either list comprehension, but before that, you need to understand how to use for loop.

Comment: If you know you always want to peek ahead three spaces, you could stop the iteration three spaces short of the end of the list.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better way than a loop to achieve it

Comment: Show us a couple of examples of your input list `l` and expected output. It's easier to understand from that than from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need second, third, fourth variables at all:

```py
#instead of second, third, fourth variables, use a list:
some_list = []
i = 1
while (index + i) < len(l):
    some_list.append(l[index+i])
    i += 1
```

and when you append the values, instead of this:

```py
word.append((item, l[second], l[third], l[forth]))
```

do this:

```py
new_list = []
new_list.append(item)
for _word in some_list:
    new_list.append(_word)
word.append(tuple(new_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand the whole situation of yours but if you are trying to remove that index error, you can add an "if statement" before assigning the second, third, fourth variables.
Your code should work as follows:

```
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    word = []
    if(index+3 < len(l)):
        second = index + 1
        third = index +2
        forth = index +3
        if item == 'B' and l[second] == 'I' and l[third] == 'I' and l[forth] == 'I':
            word.append((item, l[second], l[third], l[forth]))
            word = " ".join(word[0])

        elif item == 'B':
            word.append(item)
            entities.append(word[0])

        else:
            pass
```

Please suggest if I'm wrong.

Comment: first the <= in the if statement should be <. second, the 7th line would crash if second, third, forth were not defined because the if statement didn't work.

Comment: I got the first one and edited it to '<' . If 'if' condition is not fulfilled, why would it crash as the program would not be going inside?

Comment: you don't need to append values only if that condition is met, you need to append what exists. Thats the main issue of this code